# Setting a primary key initial value with Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a new table, and I need the primary key to start at a specific value (say 1000).

I'm using Sequel with a Sinatra app.  How can I set the primary key value?

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the Sequel part, but in Postgres, either alter the sequence or use setval():

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Presumably, you'd want to use one or the other in a migration.